# .htaccess rewrite - remove all extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, file-extension

I would like a to do a rewrite rule that removes all extensions - regardless of filename

- `https://example.com/filename.extension` -> `https://example.com/filename`

for example:

- `https://example.com/horses.txt` -> `https://example.com/horses`
- `https://example.com/icecream.json` -> `https://example.com/icecream`

I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ *? [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

not working as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only reasonably do what you are asking with `MultiViews`.

For example, as simple as:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

You need to remove your existing mod_rewrite directives.

Now, a request for `example.com/horses` will be correctly routed to `/horses.txt`, or whatever file extensions you are using. `MultiViews` uses mod_negotiation.

This isn't so easy to do with mod_rewrite, since you need to test each file extension in turn in order to work out what file you need to rewrite back to in order to route the request correctly. eg. Should a request for `example.com/horses` route to `/horses.txt` or `horses.jpg`? MultiViews does this comparison for you.

> I would like a to do a rewrite rule that removes all extensions

Although, you need to actually *remove* the file extension in the HTML source. This isn't something you do in `.htaccess`, unless you need to preserve SEO or backlinks that have already linked back to the old URLs.

> **UPDATE:** Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, I would like the url to display without the extension even if it is linked to it, or to go to that file if linked without the extension

Well, you need to actually remove the file extension on all your internal links. You can issue a "redirect" in `.htaccess` to remove the extension for the benefit of search engines and 3rd party links - but if you rely on this for your internal links then it will potentially slow users and your site as you are doubling the number of requests hitting your server.

To remove the file extension for direct requests (SEO / 3rd party links), you could do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.[\w]{2,4}$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This does assume that the only dot in the URL-path is the one that delimits the file extension.

The difficult part is then internally rewriting the request back to the underlying file *with* an extension - that's where `MultiViews` comes in (first part of my answer).

Comment: So the answer is basically a no.

Comment: I have to ask the other way round, how do you mod rewrite https://example.com/filename  -> https://example.com/filename.extension ?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, I would like the url to display without the extension even if it is linked to it, or to go to that file if linked without the extension

Comment: "I have to ask the other way round" - Well, only because you should already be linking to the file without the file extension. The hard part (and the most important part) is rewriting the request back to the underlying filesystem path. I've updated my answer to include a redirect to actually remove the file extension.